# encapsulation in objective c

Tags: objective-c, encapsulation

I am a bit confused about encapsulation. In general (or in Obj-C), does it mean separation of interface/implementation OR does it imply access of ivars through methods ?

Please clarify. Thank you.

Comment: 9 questions, no accepted answers, no votes and a seeming reluctance to use Wikipedia. What's up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, Both.

As **nacho4d** said, you encapsulate instance variables within your class and prevent direct access to them by using methods and properties to read and write their values.  This ensures that the instance can always know when something has read or written a value whereas direct ivar access is no different from setting a value in a C struct.

However, the separation of `@interface` from `@implementation` also contributes greatly to encapsulation.  And one of the goals of the enhancements to the language in the past few years has been to increase the degree of encapsulation offered by that separation.

Namely, the class's primary `@interface` can now contain *only* the parts of your class that you want other developers/code to interact with.  The public interface, if you will.   *All* of the implementation details can be moved out of the `@interface` in the latest compilers, including all instance variables.

Comment: That's not quite true; 32bit OS X Cocoa, and hence also the iPhone simulator, still require all instance variables to be declared inside the header so that their order is explicit. See http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/03/dynamic-ivars-solving-fragile-base.html

Comment: Using the latest developer tools, and the 64bit ABI, I believe that it is indeed possible to declare instance variables in a class extension interface. Someone correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yup;  and, in the latest iOS releases, the simulator's runtime, though 32 bit, works just like the runtime on the device!

Answer (score 0):

The latter. From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29):

> A language mechanism for restricting
>   access to some of the object's
>   components.

Specifically in Objective-C an ivar will be @protected by default, so they only can be accessed within the same class or subclasses. can change it to @private or @public as you need.

The methods you mentioned are accessors (getters and setters) and in that case you probably want to use @properties since they can be defined in 1 line and you can set some attributes like retain, assign, copy, readonly, etc.
Read further on properties [here (Apple doc)](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html)

Answer (score 0):

Hiding of Class methods and variables from once class to other is called encapsulation.